# Multiple OR statements in EF4 query

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to create a query that would do something like :

```
column like 'a' or column like 'B' or column like 'C' //unknown number of OR
```

How can I do this in EF4 , in nHibernate I would have a disjunction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to build an Expression Tree dynamically. Take a look at the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

The PredicateBuilder can help you to dynamically build expression trees.

Answer (score 0):

If you want full match (your example show only full match) you can do this:

```
string items = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
var query = from x in context.Entities
            where items.Contains(x.Column)
            select x;
```

It works only in EF 4+ and it is translated to `column IN ('a', 'b', c')`. For more advanced generic solution you will really need dynamically build expression tree as mentioned by @Wouter de Kort or use ESQL where you write query as a string (and you can combine as many strings as you need). If you expect wildcard searching with complex search patterns you will have to use ESQL or at least create model defined function reused in dynamically created expression tree.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches you can do this. But you should know the advantages and disadvantages for each one. See how performs LINQ to SQL, PredicateBuilder from LINQKit and Stored Procedures to accomplish this task!

http://kalcik.net/2014/01/05/joining-data-in-memory-with-data-in-database-table/